# Compilador no me detecta clase implementada

Tags: java, linux

estoy realizando un código que simula el funcionamiento de un banco con sus cuentas y todo. Las cuentas están guardadas en una lista, y cada una contiene un número de cuenta, un saldo y un titular. A su vez, el titular contiene el nombre, la dirección, el teléfono... El problema se encuentra en esta clase: Titular implementa una interfaz TitularInterfaz, y tengo que implementar todos sus métodos:

```
package fp2.poo.utilidades;


import  fp2.poo.utilidades.DniInterfaz;
import  fp2.poo.utilidades.DomicilioInterfaz;
import  fp2.poo.utilidades.CorreoElectronicoInterfaz;
import  fp2.poo.utilidades.TelefonoInterfaz;

public interface TitularInterfaz {

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo de configuracion del atributo nombre.          
     */
    public void setNombre( String nombre );

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo getter de nombre.          
     */
    public String getNombre( );


    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo de configuracion del atributo 
     *               relacionado con el primer apellido.          
     */
    public void setPrimerApellido( String primerApellido);

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo getter del primer apellido.          
     */
    public String getPrimerApellido( );

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo de configuracion del atributo 
     *               relacionado con el segundo apellido.          
     */
    public void setSegundoApellido( String segundoApellido);

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo getter del segundo apellido.          
     */
    public String getSegundoApellido( );


    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo getter del dni.          
     */
   public void setDni(DniInterfaz obj );

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo getter del dni.          
     */
    public DniInterfaz getDni( );

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo de configuracion del atributo domicilio.          
     */
    public void  setDomicilio( DomicilioInterfaz domicilio );

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo getter del domicilio.          
     */
    public DomicilioInterfaz getDomicilio( );

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo setter de correo electronico.          
     */
    public void                      setCorreoElectronico(CorreoElectronicoInterfaz email);

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo getter de correo electronico.          
     */
    public CorreoElectronicoInterfaz getCorreoElectronico();    

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo setter de telefono.          
     */
    public void setTelefono(TelefonoInterfaz titular);

    /*
     *  Descripcion: Metodo getter de telefono.          
     */
    public TelefonoInterfaz          getTelefono();

}
```

Esa es nuestra interfaz. La clase creada por mí es la siguiente:

```
package fp2.poo.pfpoofp2;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.TitularInterfaz;

public class Titular implements TitularInterfaz {
    String nombre;
    String primerapellido;
    String segundoapellido;
    Dni dni;
    Domicilio domicilio;
    CorreoElectronico correo;
    Telefono tfno;

    public void setNombre( String nombre ){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getNombre(){
    return this.nombre;
    }
    public void setPrimerApellido( String primerApellido ){
    this.primerapellido = primerApellido;
    }
    public String getPrimerApellido(){
    return this.primerapellido;
    }
    public void setSegundoApellido( String segundoApellido ){
    this.segundoapellido = segundoApellido;
    }
    public String getSegundoApellido(){
    return this.segundoapellido;
    }
    public void setDni(Dni obj){
    this.dni = obj;
    }
    public Dni getDni(){
    return this.dni;
    }
    public void setDomicilio (Domicilio domicilio){
    this.domicilio = domicilio;
    }
    public Domicilio getDomicilio(){
    return this.domicilio;
    }
    public void setCorreoElectronico(CorreoElectronico email){
    this.correo = email;
    }
    public CorreoElectronico getCorreoElectronico(){
    return this.correo;
    }
    public void setTelefono(Telefono titular){
    this.tfno = titular;
    }
    public Telefono getTelefono(){
    return this.tfno;
    }

}
```

Todas las clases están bien implementadas, pero cuando compilo me dice que el método abstracto setTelefono de la interfaz no está sobrecargado en la clase Titular. ¿A qué se debe esto? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

En la interface:

```
public void setTelefono(TelefonoInterfaz titular);
```

En tu clase:

```
public void setTelefono(Telefono titular){
    this.tfno = titular;
}
```

Es decir, tu clase no implementa un *setTelefono* que acepte un *TelefonoInterfaz*. Así que *setTelefono(TelefonoInterfaz)* no está implementada.

Incluso si *Telefono* implementa/extiende *TelefonoInterfaz*, el método no sirve. Porque puede haber otra clase (llamémosla *TelefonoB*) que también implemente *TelefonoInterfaz*. Y tenemos que:

```
TitularInterfaz titularInterfaz = .... // Asignación de una instancia
titularInterfaz.setTelefono(new TelefonoB("1234"));
```

es legal, ya que el método *setTelefono* acepta cualquier instancia que implemente *TelefonoInterfaz*

Pero:

```
Titular titular = ... // Asignación de una instancia
titularInterfaz.setTelefono(new TelefonoB("1234"));
```

es ilegal, ya que tu *setTelefono* solo acepta instancias de *Telefono*.

Como tu definición de *setTelefono* no tiene los mismos parametros del mismo tipo de la interfaz, no implementa el método de la interfaz.

De hecho, tampoco te sirve tener un método *setTelefono* que acepte una superclase (por ejemplo *setTelefono(Object)*); tienes que tener definido un método que cumpla estrictamente con la declaración en la interface.

---

La notación *@Override* sirve para avisarte cuando crees que un método implementa/extiende un método de la interfaz/superclase pero en realidad no lo hace:

```
@Override // Te mostrará un error porque este método no está relacionado con un método de una superclase o interfaz.
public void setTelefono(Telefono titular){
    this.tfno = titular;
}
```

Comment: Vale, ya lo he probado y parece funcionar. Muchas gracias!